# Google Cloud Container Registry Subdirectory Create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-cloud-registry

I have an image in `registry1` and want to copy it over to a `registry2`.

Assuming I would get that done by running this command (as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing)):

`gcloud container images add-tag \ gcr.io/registry1/image1:tag1 \ gcr.io/registry2/subdirectory/image1:tag1`

But I want to create a **new subdirectory** within the registry2 it's being moved such as:

`gcr.io/registry2/subdirectory/image1:tag1` how can I create it?

Also, I'm super new to GCR. Are these called subdirectories, folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called `repositories` not folders or directories! See [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#repos).

BTW, Google Container Registry (gcr) doesn't provide full control on these `repositories`, moreover, you can't assign specific `IAM` role/s to specific `repository`. to get these options, move to [`Artifact Registry`](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry).

---

To create a repository in `gcr`, you need to have write access to the registry. and don't do it with gcloud, I mean don't re-tag the source image while it is still in your source repo.

To do that, just pull the source image locally and then re-tag it using `docker` with the full tag

```
gcr.io/registry2/repository/image1:tag1
```

then push it and that's it! your image should be pushed to the destination repository in `registry2`. See [Pushing an image to a registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry)